# Renderable object abstraction

Tags: architecture, sprites, rendering

In my engine I have 2 types of 2D renderables: sprites and groups (and maybe primitives later). Sprites are just textured quads and groups are multiple renderables grouped in a single object. I have this drawcall system now:

```
struct Renderable
{
    virtual void Render(Renderer& renderer) = 0;
};

struct Sprite : public Renderable
{
    Texture& texture;
    // other sprite specific stuff
    void Render(Renderer& renderer) override { renderer.RenderSprite(...); }
};

struct Group : public Renderable
{
    vector<Renderable*> elements;
    // Other group related stuff like a transformation matrix
    void Render(Renderer& renderer) override
    {
        for (Renderable* r : elements)
            r->Render(renderer);
    }
};
```

Instead of sendig them straight to the renderer, I need an indirection. This makes rendering many (like 20K) sprites super slow. Is there a better design to avoid indirection (or even abstraction)?